# Spark limit number of executors to load a Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

i have a spark job which reads data in a Dataset < Row > userInfo. And then multiple dataset are joined with userInfo.

Userinfo is stored on hdfs with 500 partitions for better parallelisation. In spark, I have dynamic scaling enabled with limit of 100 executors and 1 core on each executor.

With this setup whenever application starts it brings up 100 executor and every executor stores some portion of the 500 partitions. Since every executor is having data autoscaling does not reclaim containers. It results in lots of resources being wasted. **Is it possible to limit the storage of UserInfo to some executors only (let's say 10)** so that other containers can be reclaimed when no task is running on them.

I can see few options to do it, but they don't look good to me because of reasons

1. store using .persist(disk_only). **NO** because reading from disk is equivalently bad to reading remotely in our case.
2. store using .cache() and enable spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout. **NO** because we don't want executors having userinfo to be reclaimed and having to re read the data.
3. reading data in lesser number of partitions that we want to retain i.e. 10. In this case since the data has to be read in 10 partitions, at max 10 executors will be used to retain data. This approach might have been fine but storing in 10 partitions means every time i have to do join i will have to repartition. Which i would want to avoid.